# How To Create a case Or Incident In Microsoft Dynamics Online CRM using php-crm-toolkit

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to create case it's giving me

> "Fatal error: Uncaught AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\SoapFault: You should specify a parent contact or account. in D:\wamp64\www\php_crm\vendor\alexacrm\php-crm-toolkit\src\Client.php on line 1159"

My code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Use init.php if you didn't install the package via Composer
 */
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;



$options = [
    'serverUrl' => '**********************',
    'username' => '****************',
    'password' => '*************',
    'authMode' => '***********************',
];

$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings );


// create a new contact
$incident = $service->entity( 'incident' );
$incident->title = 'Test Created With Proxy';
$incident->description = 'This is a test incident';
$incidentId = $incident->create();

?>
```

Comment: ehm, so what's your question? what you tried?

Comment: I want to create "Customer Services - All Cases" using php.      I'm using https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created case by using following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Use init.php if you didn't install the package via Composer
 */
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\EntityReference;

$options = [
    'serverUrl' => '**************************',
    'username' => '**********************',
    'password' => '*****************',
    'authMode' => 'OnlineFederation',
];


$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings );

$contact = $service->entity( 'contact' );
$contact->firstname = 'John';
$contact->lastname = 'Doe';
$contact->emailaddress1 = 'john.doe@example.com';
$guid = $contact->create();

$incident = $service->entity('incident');
//echo '<pre>';print_r($incident);echo '</pre>';
$incident->title = 'Test Created With Proxy';
$incident->description = 'This is a test incident';
$incident->customerid = new EntityReference( 'contact', $guid );
//$incident->ID = $guid;//contactid responsiblecontactid primarycontactid
$incidentId = $incident->create();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, you must mention the customer of the incident - Parent account or contact. Check the below code, it should work (not sure about php syntax).

```
$incident = $service->entity( 'incident' );
$incident->title = 'Test Created With Proxy';
$incident->description = 'This is a test incident';
$incident->customerid = new EntityReference( 'contact', 'GUID HERE' );
$incidentId = $incident->create();
```

[Reference](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit/issues/25)

From the above link, adding another snippet for lookup field assignment:

```
$customer = $client->entity( 'contact' );
$customer->ID = 'GUID HERE';
$incident-> customerid = $customer;
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, Could you please let me know how we can get <guid>?

Comment: @PHPMagentoDeveloper guid is the primary key of any CRM record - basically looks like 32 digits with dashes. https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2016/07/10/how-to-get-guid-of-the-record-in-crm-online/

Comment: Also I am getting following error
Notice: Undefined property via __set() - incident does not support property: customerid_contact in D:\wamp64\www\php_crm\test.php on line 37 in D:\wamp64\www\php_crm\vendor\alexacrm\php-crm-toolkit\src\Entity.php on line 264"

Comment: @PHPMagentoDeveloper really sorry, I typed it from my memory.. also am not sure if you use web api or odata api. Try with customerid

Comment: Thanks for your help, getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EntityReference' not found

Comment: @PHPMagentoDeveloper updated the answer, I don’t have any other clue :) is it easy to setup php environment or any codepen kinda thing available to test these myself first..?

Comment: Great Thanks for reply, Do we have any document for this?

Comment: How can i get the contact id from crm?

Comment: Hi Arun,    Coould you please have a look on following issue?

https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit/issues/90